# crc16 ccitt from a byte array

Tags: vb.net, crc16

1. I need some help with creating checksum for tcp packet from an array
   of byte.
2. This is code is working as I've tested it with
   string.
3. Problem is I've to pass an array of byte to this
   function.
4. At this moment I've created it simple by using hard
   embedded time serial number otherwise it is very long code to login
   to a device.
5. Value of this is b1:68:de:3a:15:cd:5b:07 checked with wireshark and CRC should be E2B6 checked with online crc [this](http://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/crc-calculation.html)
6. Now, coming to main point I just can't call this method as this method is expecting some string values and I've to pass hex values. How I can do that.

   ```
   Private Sub ConnectTCP_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ConnectTCP.Click
   Dim Serial As UInt32 = "123456789"
   Dim time As UInt32 = "987654321"
   Dim buffer2() As Byte = BitConverter.GetBytes(time)
   Dim buffer3() As Byte = BitConverter.GetBytes(Serial)
   Dim array4(buffer2.Length + buffer3.Length - 1) As Byte
   Array.Copy(buffer2, array4, buffer2.Length)
   Array.Copy(buffer3, 0, array4, buffer2.Length, buffer3.Length)
   getCRC16(array4) 'What I need to do here
          end sub
   ```

"CRC16 CCITT function""

```
Public Function getCRC16(ByVal strInput As String)
    Dim lngCheck As Long
    Dim Power(7) As Integer
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim J As Integer
    Dim Poly As Long
    Dim CRC As Long
    Dim TestBit As Boolean
    Dim TestBit1 As Boolean
    Dim TestBit2 As Boolean
    Poly = &H1021
    CRC = &HFFFF
    For J = 0 To 7
        Power(J) = 2 ^ J
    Next J
    For I = 1 To Len(strInput)
        lngCheck = Asc(Mid$(strInput, I, 1))
        For J = 7 To 0 Step -1
            If (CRC And 32768) = 32768 Then
                TestBit1 = True
            Else
                TestBit1 = False
            End If
            If (lngCheck And Power(J)) = Power(J) Then
                TestBit2 = True
            Else
                TestBit2 = False
            End If
            TestBit = TestBit1 Xor TestBit2
            CRC = (CRC And 32767) * 2
            If TestBit = True Then
                CRC = CRC Xor Poly
            End If
        Next J
    Next I
    Dim tmp As String
    tmp = Hex(CRC)
    CRCTCP.Text = tmp
    getCRC16 = tmp
End Function
```

Comment: `BitConverter.ToString(array4)` ?                  _Converts the numeric value of each element of a specified array of bytes to its equivalent hexadecimal string representation._

Comment: Hi Alex, What happened is when you use bitconverter.tostring it treat "b1:68:de:3a:15:cd:5b:07" as "b'' "1" "6" so forth as single character and whole crc thing get changed.

Comment: it is hex value of "123456789" "987654321". You can try windows calculator for conversion from decimal to hex. But It will show front to back.  When you send any packet it gets converted to hex.

Answer (score -1):

Finally, Found It.

```
Public Class CRC16CCITT
    Public Enum InitialCRCValue
        Zeroes = 0
        NonZero1 = &HFFFF
        NonZero2 = &H1D0F
        'NonZero3 = &H0
    End Enum

    Private Const poly As UShort = &H1021 'polynomial
    Dim table(255) As UShort
    Dim intValue As UShort = 0

    Public Function ComputeCheckSum(ByVal bytes As Byte()) As UShort
        Dim crc As UShort = Me.intValue
        'Dim x As String
        For i As Integer = 0 To bytes.Length - 1
            crc = CUShort(((crc << 8) Xor table(((crc >> 8) Xor (&HFF And bytes(i))))))
            'crc = (crc << 8) ^ (x << 15) ^ (x << 2) ^ x
        Next
        Return crc
    End Function

    Public Function ComputeCheckSumBytes(ByVal bytes As Byte()) As Byte()
        Dim crc As UShort = ComputeCheckSum(bytes)
        Return BitConverter.GetBytes(crc)
    End Function

    Public Sub New(ByVal initialvalue As InitialCRCValue)
        Me.intValue = CUShort(initialvalue)
        Dim temp, a As UShort
        For i As Integer = 0 To table.Length - 1
            temp = 0
            a = CUShort(i << 8)
            For j As Integer = 0 To 7
                If ((temp Xor a) And &H8000) <> 0 Then
                    temp = CUShort((temp << 1) Xor poly)
                Else
                    temp <<= 1
                End If
                a <<= 1
            Next
            table(i) = temp
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```